# ¿Determinar el tiempo de ejecución en microsegundos para C (Windows)?

Tags: c, time

Quiero obtener el tiempo de ejecución de una función en microsegundos en C. El problema es que no se como hacerlo.

Tengo un for que llama dos funciones 1000 veces. La idea es calcular el tiempo de duración de cada función.

Codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int TAMANO = 2000;
const int REPETICIONES = 1000;

int main() {
  int arreglo [TAMANO];
  int arreglo2 [TAMANO];
  long tiempoInicial;
  long tiempoFinal;
  long totalSecuencia = 0;
  long totalBinaria = 0;
  int datoABuscar;

  srand(time(NULL));
  llenarArreglo(arreglo);
  datoABuscar = rand() % TAMANO;

  for (int j = 0; j < REPETICIONES; j++) {
    // Copio el arreglo a arreglo2 
    for (int x = 0; x < TAMANO; x++) {
      arreglo2[x] = arreglo[x];
    }
    // Quiero calcular el tiempo en microsegundos de la función secuencial y binaria.
    secuencial(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
    burbuja(arreglo2);
    binaria(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
  }

  // La idea es mostrar los tiempos aqui.
  printf("Secuencia: %ld\n", totalSecuencia);
  printf("Binaria: %ld", totalBinaria);

}
```

En lo respecta a las funciones secuencia(), burbuja(), binaria() son los algoritmos de ordenación y búsqueda respectivos.

Una mano, gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que tienes hasta ahora? Échale un vistazo a  [ask] y a cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Hay agregue un parte.

Comment: Para obtener el tiempo en microsegundos, ¿qué debería usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html), que es una solución POSIX:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t diffTime(struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end)
{
      return (((end->tv_sec * 1000===000) + end->tv_nsec) -
             ((start->tv_sec * 1000000000) + start->tv_nsec)) * 1000;
}

int main()
{
  int64_t totalSecuencial = 0;
  int64_t totalBurbuja    = 0;
  int64_t totalBinaria    = 0;

  // ...

  for (int j = 0; j < REPETICIONES; j++) {
    struct timespec start, end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    secuencial(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    totalSecuencial += diffTime(&start,&end);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    burbuja(arreglo2);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    totalBurbuja += diffTime(&start,&end);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    binaria(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    totalBinaria += diffTime(&start,&end);
  }

  printf("Secuencia: %" PRId64 "\n", totalSecuencial);
  printf("Burbuja: %" PRId64 "\n",   totalBurbuja);
  printf("Binaria: %" PRId64 "\n",   totalBinaria);

  return 0;
}
```

o [timespec_get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get), disponible desde el estándar C11:

```
for (int j = 0; j < REPETICIONES; j++) {
  struct timespec start, end;

  timespec_get(&start,TIME_UTC);
  secuencial(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
  timespec_get(&end,TIME_UTC);
  totalSecuencial += diffTime(&start,&end);

  timespec_get(&start,TIME_UTC);
  burbuja(arreglo2);
  timespec_get(&end,TIME_UTC);
  totalBurbuja += diffTime(&start,&end);

  timespec_get(&start,TIME_UTC);
  binaria(arreglo2, datoABuscar);
  timespec_get(&end,TIME_UTC);
  totalBinaria += diffTime(&start,&end);
}
```

Comment: Que hace referencia  CLOCK_MONOTONIC y TIME_UTC. ¿Cómo las defino?

Comment: @mb0 están en time.h

Comment: ¿la unidad de tiempo esta en micro-segundos?

Comment: No importa, ya lo solucione. Muchas gracias.